# Send textfield text of viewcontroller object to a different class

Tags: objective-c

I have a ViewController that has a setting in which the user puts some data into the text field. To give more context, the text field is the directory the user wants to upload their file to. There is some text already there, `/var/www`, since that is default for most servers. However, I want the user to be able to change the text. In the class that uploads the file, I instantiate a SettingsViewController object, like so:

```
SettingsViewController *accessSettings = [SettingsViewController alloc]init];
```

Then, I try to access its text field text, but obviously, since the view hasn't loaded yet, I only get `null`. How do I go about fixing this? I've tried using delegates, but that still doesn't solve the issue of the text field not loading yet. Any help would be great!
Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class `Setting` for user setting. And it include a property of the directory. Then you can define a public `Setting` property in `SettingsViewController`.

```
SettingsViewController *accessSettings = [SettingsViewController alloc]init];
// Here I suppose you init the self.setting at some place.
accessSettings.setting = self.setting;
```

Then in `SettingsViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField.text = self.setting.directory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But does viewDidLoad get fired when the object is initialized? That's what I was confused about.

Comment: You will definitely show the `SettingsViewController`, right? And before that is shown, it will be firstly loaded. That is, `viewDidLoad` will be fired. You can take a look at the view life cycle to get a deep understanding.

Comment: I will only if the user wants to change the default setting, that I've already put in

Comment: Now I'm confused about what do you want to do. Do you have other problems?

Comment: I'm trying to access the text in a text field, that is inputted in a view controller, that doesn't get loaded, but I just need its properties

Comment: As shown in my answer, you can NOT. But you can give it your text. Later when it's loaded you can set the `textField`'s text.